# how to update a column from another database?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to update a field that has been delete from the backup database.
how can I update the field from an other database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved I by using `dblink`

I created the extension

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

then I used it as:

```
UPDATE my_table t SET  column_name=i.column_name, 
FROM  dblink('dbname=other_db','SELECT id, x_column_name FROM my_table') as i(id INT, column_name TEXT) where t.id=i.id;
```

Comment: This is updating the current database by using data of a different database. Is it possible to update table in a different database (via dblink) by using data of the current database?
In my case, I can use dblink in one database (current), but cannot use it in another (different) (because one has "trust" permissions active, which I cannot change).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write an SQL statement that affects tables from different databases, the best option is to use a [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) foreign table.

But perhaps it is simpler to extract the data from one database to a file using `COPY` and to load the file into the other database.

Answer (score 0):

m3asmi's way helped me but it was asking for database username & password in my windows machine so i tried this & worked like a charm!

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

then:

```
UPDATE my_table t SET  column_name=i.column_name, 
FROM  dblink('dbname=other_db password=dbpassword user=dbuser','SELECT id, x_column_name FROM my_table') as i(id INT, column_name TEXT) where t.id=i.id;
```